# using an Activity as preference activity?

Tags: android, eclipse

Is it possible to use a normal `Activity` as a preference `Activity`?

I know you can do this with preference `Activity`, but what i am trying to do is make a layout which contains a `CheckBox`, `Buttons`, and/or a `ListView`. So basically a normal layout in xml.

But is it possible to have those items be preferences sort of like they do in a preference screen? So overall i am trying to make a preferences in an `Activity` from a layout.

Comment: I dont think it is possible. Why do you want to use a normal activity?

Comment: Guess what i am trying to do is make sort of a custom preference screen but not in the normal way. Basically trying to make a completely different layout to hold the preferences like checkboxes and listviews...

Comment: Why dont you use CheckBoxPreference or ListPreference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation you would have found: [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) with this available you have **NO** reason to use a Activity. While this is still doable, its not recommended, use what is available.

Comment: Simple reason: My app is for android 2.2 and Up. But From 3.0 some parts ot PreferenceActivity are deprecated. Possible solutions: 1. separate bilds. 2.Take a risk and continue to use deprecated parts. 3. Write your own activity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. you can directly read and write values from preference xml without preference activity

For reading preference xml values, you can use code like given below

```
int value = this.getSharedPreferences("PreferenceFileName", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("PreferenceName", 1);
```

to write value to preference xml value, use some thing similar to this

```
Editor e = this.getSharedPreferences("PreferenceFileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
e.putInt("PreferenceName", newvalue  );
e.commit();
```

you need to read the values when activity is shown and save it when leaving activity. But if you are looking for easiest way to save preference then use preference activity.